# Looking for a Windows equivalent of SOQLExplorer

Tags: soql, ide, developer-console

I need to be able to create SOQL on my windows Laptop, I am very used to SOQLExplorer on my Mac however this is not built for Windows. Is there an equivalent out there for Windows?

Answer (score 5):

I use RealForceExplorer and I am very happy with it.
Create SOQL, SOSL and anonymous Apex.
Multiple windows, multiple connections to orgs.

Check it out here https://bitbucket.org/realforceexplorer/real-force-explorer/wiki/Home

Comment: i've used forceexplore on windows for a while and i'll have to check out RealForceExplorer

Comment: So what is the verdict here... which is the best tool or equivalent to SOQLExplorer? My preference is workbench.developerforce.com, however it doesn't support nested Soql's query.

Comment: It was a tie, between Query Editor and RealForceExplorer. Each of those got two votes. My favourite is RealForceExplorer.

Comment: We are the team behind Realforce. Rebranded version of it has been released at https://www.datasert.com/products/realforce

Comment: @datasert your SSL cert may be busted?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Just tested website in chrome, safari and firefox. It loads fine. We use let's encrypt. If you still see issue, can you please elaborate?

Comment: @datasert Looks good now

Answer (score 3):

Try the Query Editor in the Developer Console.  It allows you to enter and run SOQL queries.  For more information, look [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_tab_query_editor.htm&language=en_US).

It's not perfect; a lot of the time all you get for an error message is something like "syntax error".  Still, it's much better than debugging SOQL via log files.

Answer (score 2):

Cloudingo also have a free explorer: http://www.cloudingo.com/studio

I've used it on occasion, you can export your query into excel which I have found useful.

Comment: Cloudingo Studio is no longer functional due to lacking TLS 1.1 support...

Answer (score 2):

I've heard good things about the [FuseIT Salesforce Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer.aspx).